# How to match mean and standard deviation of 2 datasets for data that cannot be less than 0 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, mean, data-transform

I have two datasets of monthly precipitation sums at a certain location. One of them is observed, the other is modelled by a climate model. I want to match the mean and standard deviation of both datasets, so that the time series from the model matches with those from the observations. However, when I apply the formula, some negative values occur in the time series of the modelled monthly precipitation sums in order to make the standard deviation fit. I wonder whether there is a solution for this or if anyone knows how I can solve this.

```
data_mod=[70.74191271   66.54238669 28.60091702 55.56554018 66.04186858 77.06576381 72.57394329 99.62497103 42.51156832 22.81012399 107.3993961 48.45702239 33.71119171 61.09975519 74.43277952 39.14433747 113.1039794 67.93592923 96.95537867 12.99913771 53.6158074  48.05637989 52.27533536 99.27060261 54.73806827 148.462539  17.94473213 93.65016815 32.89454535 52.36015655];
data_obs=[27    38.6    146.1   61.8    44.6    7.5 50.4    23.2    8.1 89.7    23.1    83.3    86.5    46  14.5    27.7    81  30  50.3    165.7   15.5    106.7   56.7    52.5    75.1    100.1   6.9 18.7    93.4    16.6];
data_transformed = mean(data_obs(:)) + (data_mod - mean(data_mod(:)))*(std(data_obs(:))/std(data_mod(:)));
mean(data_transformed(:))
std(data_transformed(:))
```

Comment: This question focusses on the modelling aspect (rather than the technical aspects of implementing in MATLAB). You'd probably be better off posting in cross-validated. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20209/normal-like-distribution-over-a-bounded-area) for a similar question which might help, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution). Post any questions you have about implementing the models in MATLAB here.